# React routing link is text and not a link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
  <div>
     <Link to={'/search'}>Trying out routing - Search </Link>
   </div>
```

Why is this the text `Trying out routing - Search` appearing in my browser as text rather than as a clickable link?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of react version change.Now the current version 15.4.2

```
 <Link to='/search'>Trying out routing - Search </Link>
```

Kindly try the above code and it will work.